# How to activate navbar-toggle earlier than default

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu

when I resize my webpage my menu falls apart before transitioning into navbar-toggle as can be seen in the image. How can I change when it transitions to navbar-toggle ?

Thanks !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGD8h.png

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using bootstrap v3 or above. Yoou can go to this link: [customize bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints) and change the pixel sizes in the @screen-xs box to be something larger, then scroll to the bottom and click "Compileand Download" to get a customised bootstrap.css file that you should use instead of the standard one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Is there a way I can do it through editing css or js file that I currently have since I've already made some changes in them and therefore can't replace it with this custom one. I've tried searching bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js but couldn't find it.

Comment: A good tip when using bootstrap is to use your own css file (eg style.css) in addition to the bootstrap one and leave the bootstrap one untouched. You can then override any bootstrap styles i your own file so it will still look how you want, but it will allow you to change bootstrap version easier. As for your current problem, you are going to have to find each instance of @media in the css file an d if it is too small (like 480px) make it something bigger (whatever the width of you menu is)

Comment: Hi TheWaxMann , thanks for the reply. this is my first project using bootstrap so I made that rookie mistake of making some changes to the bootstrap.css , but I've later started doing them through my own .css file. I'll try your suggestion.